# How to Group This SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The SQL statement below produce sums of data for months and displays the columns as years.

The problem, as you will see in the image below, is that the result set has null values.   Is there a way to represent the dataset for each month once?

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%M') AS M,
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2015
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2015',
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2016
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2016',
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2017
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2017',
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2018
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2018'
FROM
    phases_required b
        RIGHT JOIN
    projects a ON b.project_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        t2.project_id, ROUND(reimbursable_percent, 0) AS percentage
    FROM
        rate_names t1, phases_required t2, rates_phase t3
    WHERE
        t1.id = t3.rate_names_id
            AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id
    GROUP BY t2.project_id) AS pcntg ON pcntg.project_id = a.id
WHERE
    start_date != '0000-00-00'
        AND DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y') NOT IN (2010 , 2012, 2013, 2014)
GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%m%Y')
```

[image: Result Set]

Here is the SQL to produce the table SQL statement you see above dynamically:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000000;
SET @sqldynamic = (

SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT( distinct

CONCAT( '(case date_format(start_date,"%Y") when ', date_format(a.start_date,"%Y") , ' then ROUND((COALESCE(sum(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(sum(b.hourly_bid_amount),0) + COALESCE(sum(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage/100 + sum(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(sum(b.subcontracted_amount),0)),2)+COALESCE(sum(b.subcontracted_amount),0)+COALESCE(sum(b.contingency_1),0) end) as \'' , date_format(start_date,"%Y"),'\''
        )
    )
From phases_required b RIGHT JOIN projects a  ON b.project_id = a.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.project_id, round(reimbursable_percent,0) as percentage FROM rate_names t1,phases_required t2,rates_phase t3
WHERE t1.id = t3.rate_names_id AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id group by t2.project_id) as pcntg on pcntg.project_id =a.id
WHERE start_date != "0000-00-00" and date_format(start_date,"%Y") not in (2010,2012,2013,2014) 
);




SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date_format(start_date,"%M") as M, ', 
        @sqldynamic, ' 
    From phases_required b RIGHT JOIN projects a  ON b.project_id = a.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.project_id, round(reimbursable_percent,0) as percentage FROM rate_names t1,phases_required t2,rates_phase t3
WHERE t1.id = t3.rate_names_id AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id group by t2.project_id) as pcntg on pcntg.project_id =a.id
WHERE start_date != "0000-00-00" and date_format(start_date,"%Y") not in (2010,2012,2013,2014)
group by date_format(start_date,"%M%Y") order by date_format(start_date,"%m")'
);


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Those are different years in each row. Your final grouping is by month and year ("%m%Y").  Change it to group by month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.    Thank you Daniel Blais for helping getting me here.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000000;
SET @sqldynamic = (

SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT( distinct

CONCAT( '(case date_format(start_date,"%Y") when ', date_format(a.start_date,"%Y") , ' then ROUND((COALESCE(sum(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(sum(b.hourly_bid_amount),0) + COALESCE(sum(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage/100 + sum(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(sum(b.subcontracted_amount),0)),2)+COALESCE(sum(b.subcontracted_amount),0)+COALESCE(sum(b.contingency_1),0) end) as Y_' , date_format(start_date,"%Y")
        )
    )
From phases_required b RIGHT JOIN projects a  ON b.project_id = a.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.project_id, round(reimbursable_percent,0) as percentage FROM rate_names t1,phases_required t2,rates_phase t3
WHERE t1.id = t3.rate_names_id AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id group by t2.project_id) as pcntg on pcntg.project_id =a.id
WHERE start_date != "0000-00-00" and date_format(start_date,"%Y") not in (2010,2012,2013,2014) 
);

SET @sqlgroup = (
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct

CONCAT('sum(coalesce(Y_', date_format(a.start_date,"%Y") ,', 0)) as Y_',date_format(a.start_date,"%Y")
        )
    )
From phases_required b RIGHT JOIN projects a  ON b.project_id = a.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.project_id, round(reimbursable_percent,0) as percentage FROM rate_names t1,phases_required t2,rates_phase t3
WHERE t1.id = t3.rate_names_id AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id group by t2.project_id) as pcntg on pcntg.project_id =a.id
WHERE start_date != "0000-00-00" and date_format(start_date,"%Y") not in (2010,2012,2013,2014) 

);



SET @sql = CONCAT('select m,', @sqlgroup , ' from (SELECT date_format(start_date,"%M") as M, date_format(start_date,"%m") as m2 ,', 
        @sqldynamic, ' 
    From phases_required b RIGHT JOIN projects a  ON b.project_id = a.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.project_id, round(reimbursable_percent,0) as percentage FROM rate_names t1,phases_required t2,rates_phase t3
WHERE t1.id = t3.rate_names_id AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id group by t2.project_id) as pcntg on pcntg.project_id =a.id
WHERE start_date != "0000-00-00" and date_format(start_date,"%Y") not in (2010,2012,2013,2014)
group by date_format(start_date,"%M%Y") order by date_format(start_date,"%m")) qry group by m order by m2'
);



PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like but it should works :

```
select m,
sum(coalesce('2015', 0)) '2015',
sum(coalesce('2015', 0)) '2016', 
sum(coalesce('2015', 0)) '2017', 
sum(coalesce('2015', 0)) '2018' 
from (
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%M') AS M,
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2015
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2015',
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2016
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2016',
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2017
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2017',
    (CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y')
        WHEN
            2018
        THEN
            ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(b.bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.hourly_bid_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.other_bid_amount), 0) * pcntg.percentage / 100 + SUM(b.other_bid_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0)),
                    2) + COALESCE(SUM(b.subcontracted_amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.contingency_1), 0)
    END) AS '2018'
FROM
    phases_required b
        RIGHT JOIN
    projects a ON b.project_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        t2.project_id, ROUND(reimbursable_percent, 0) AS percentage
    FROM
        rate_names t1, phases_required t2, rates_phase t3
    WHERE
        t1.id = t3.rate_names_id
            AND t3.rates_id = t2.rates_id
    GROUP BY t2.project_id) AS pcntg ON pcntg.project_id = a.id
WHERE
    start_date != '0000-00-00'
        AND DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y') NOT IN (2010 , 2012, 2013, 2014)
GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%m%Y') 
) qry
group by m;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not.  Resulted in one line January

Comment: I forgot to `group by m`.  This should be ok now.

Comment: How to I apply that to the dynamic one?  
 @sqldynamic

Comment: Thank you I was able to update the dynamic one.  Appreciate the help